# How to Import p7s certificate chain into keystore?

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, keystore, keytool

I've used these commands to create my csr

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore domain.jks -dname "CN=*.domain.com,OU=Software Development, O=Company Name, L=Asuncion, ST=Central, C=PY"
keytool -certreq -alias server -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -file domain.csr -keystore domain.jks
```

Then I've got my certificate signed

```
Web Server CERTIFICATE
-----------------
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

INTERMEDIATE CA:
---------------------------------------
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIETTCCAzWgAwIBAgIDAjpxMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQK
Ew1HZW9UcnVzdCBJbmMuMRswGQYDVQQDExJHZW9UcnVzdCBHbG9iYWwgQ0EwHhcNMTMxMjExMjM0
NTUxWhcNMjIwNTIwMjM0NTUxWjBCMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEWMBQGA1UEChMNR2VvVHJ1c3QgSW5j
LjEbMBkGA1UEAxMSUmFwaWRTU0wgU0hBMjU2IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB
CgKCAQEAu1jBEgEul9h9GKrIwuWF4hdsYC7JjTEFORoGmFbdVNcRjFlbPbFUrkshhTIWX1SG5tmx
2GCJa1i+ctqgAEJ2sSdZTM3jutRc2aZ/uyt11UZEvexAXFm33Vmf8Wr3BvzWLxmKlRK6msrVMNI4
/Bk7WxU7NtBDTdFlodSLwWBBs9ZwF8w5wJwMoD23ESJOztmpetIqYpygC04q18NhWoXdXBC5VD0t
A/hJ8LySt7ecMcfpuKqCCwW5Mc0IW7siC/acjopVHHZDdvDibvDfqCl158ikh4tq8bsIyTYYZe5Q
Q7hdctUoOeFTPiUs2itP3YqeUFDgb5rE1RkmiQF1cwmbOwIDAQABo4IBSjCCAUYwHwYDVR0jBBgw
FoAUwHqYaI2J+6sFZAwRfap9ZbjKzE4wHQYDVR0OBBYEFJfCJ1CewsnsDIgyyHyt4qYBT9pvMBIG
A1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMDYGA1UdHwQvMC0wK6ApoCeGJWh0dHA6
Ly9nMS5zeW1jYi5jb20vY3Jscy9ndGdsb2JhbC5jcmwwLwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEIzAhMB8GCCsGAQUF
BzABhhNodHRwOi8vZzIuc3ltY2IuY29tMEwGA1UdIARFMEMwQQYKYIZIAYb4RQEHNjAzMDEGCCsG
AQUFBwIBFiVodHRwOi8vd3d3Lmdlb3RydXN0LmNvbS9yZXNvdXJjZXMvY3BzMCkGA1UdEQQiMCCk
HjAcMRowGAYDVQQDExFTeW1hbnRlY1BLSS0xLTU2OTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEANevhiyBW
lLp6vXmp9uP+bji0MsGj21hWID59xzqxZ2nVeRQb9vrsYPJ5zQoMYIp0TKOTKqDwUX/N6fmS/Zar
RfViPT9gRlATPSATGC6URq7VIf5Dockj/lPEvxrYrDrK3maXI67T30pNcx9vMaJRBBZqAOv5jUOB
8FChH6bKOvMoPF9RrNcKRXdLDlJiG9g4UaCSLT+Qbsh+QJ8gRhVd4FB84XavXu0R0y8TubglpK9Y
Ca81tGJUheNI3rzSkHp6pIQNo0LyUcDUrVNlXWz4Px8G8k/Ll6BKWcZ40egDuYVtLLrhX7atKz4l
ecWLVtXjCYDqwSfC2Q7sRwrp0Mr82A==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I also received a p7s file (domain.com.p7s)

I've tried in many different ways to import it properly into the keystore but I get the error that shows in this page https://thedomain.com/ > ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

What is the command to import this chain ? this is not the first time I am doing this but this time I just can't get it to work.

Comment: You have to import the signed certificate chain using the same alias you used to generate the keypair and CSR, and *without* the -trustcas option.

Comment: @EJP Please answer the comment I will upvote and mark as answered. It worked ! THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the signed certificate chain using the same alias you used to generate the keypair and CSR, and without the `-trustcacerts` option.

Basically something like this

```
keytool -import -alias server -file domain.p7s -keystore domain.jks
```